# A good example of a series that cannot be seperated into two seperate sums?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm a TA in calculus and while working with infinite series, one of my students separated a series into two sums even though each sum/series diverged. However, it worked out in the end because it was a telescoping series. However, do you have a good example of a series that I can use to show why you have to be cautious? A series that converges, but both individual series diverges (And not a telescoping series).

---

Consider $a_n=1/n$. The series we worked with was the following series, where he used the rule without checking. $$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(a_{n}-a_{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n}-a_{1}\right)=a_{1}=1
$$
However, if I remember correctly the second equality only holds if both series are converging. However, both sums $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$,$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n+1}$ are diverging.

Comment: $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$? It converges with no cancellation of terms, but if you split it into positive and negative terms each sum diverges.